# VS2017 Installation failure; unable to report through Installer or the Microsoft Development Community

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio 2017 Installer error that I haven't been able to fix using any of the suggestions I have seen before. Additionally I have not been able to report my errors through the appropriate channels.

**My System**

Windows 7 Professional SP1, latest Windows Updates. I have VS2005 (woah, I know, right?), VS2008, VS2013, and I briefly had VS2017 in the past.

**The Main Issue**

1. I run VS2017 Installer (regular or right-click run as admin). It fails with Message Box 1:

> {no title}: "A product matching the following parameters cannot be
>   found: channelId: VisualStudio.15.Release productId:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise"

[image]

2. I press OK, I get MessageBox 2:

> "Elevation Required": "This program requires administrator privileges
>   to perform setup operations. Please rerun the program as
>   administrator."

(note: I am running with elevated privileges)

[image]

3. I then tried to report the error and **it doesn't even give me the option to sign in**. It just says

> Error signing in: 'Unknown'

[image]

**What Else I have Tried**

1. I have tried every suggestion that Microsoft employees have suggested here (3+ times):

   - uninstalling VS2017 installer (this fails unless I rename/delete `"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer”` as many of the troubleshooters have suggested).
   - I have tried `"InstallCleanup.exe -full"`
   - I even tried using the github/VisualStudioUninstaller
   - I reinstalled .NET Framework 4.7.

Nothing works or changes the error.

2. I tried to report this on Microsoft's Developer community and got this:

> Access Denied" "We're sorry but you do not have permission to do the
>   activity you attempted. If you believe this to be an error, please
>   contact your administrators.

[image]

---

3. I have the vscollect logs, which I tried to attach to the Microsoft case. I can provide a link to them if needed.

---

4. Here are the installer logs:

> 2018-07-20T15:22:00 : Verbose : Visual Studio Installer (1.16.1251.625
>   : release) ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\vs_installershell.exe"] 2018-07-20T15:22:02 :
>   Verbose : Creating VS Telemetry Survey 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose :
>   Starting ServiceHub Remote Settings client. 2018-07-20T15:22:02 :
>   Verbose : Received the application ready notification
>   2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose : Window showing 2018-07-20T15:22:02 :
>   Verbose : ProgressBarService listening to ipc channel: progress-bar
>   2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose : LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc
>   channel: LoggerService 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose :
>   LoggerIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: LoggerService
>   2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Warning : getRemoteSettingsIpcService called
>   more than once. 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose : FeaturesIpcRpcService
>   listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose
>   : FeaturesIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: FeaturesProxy
>   2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose : Telemetry Session ID:
>   74a96246-58e3-4723-adf5-42a4a0a76776 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Verbose :
>   Service creation finished 2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Error : Attempted
>   connection to service 'RemoteSettingsClient': location is null
>   2018-07-20T15:22:02 : Error : Remote Settings Ipc Service creation
>   failed. error: [TypeError] Path must be a string. Received undefined
>   at TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined at assertPath
>   (path.js:28:11) at Object.join (path.js:489:7) at getUserSpecificSalt
>   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:111:32)
>   at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\config.js:99:16
>   at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54) at
>   self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30) at
>   Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13) at
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44 at runSingle
>   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13) at flush
>   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13) at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) From
>   previous event: at defer (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:582:19) at
>   Promise.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\q\q.js:828:20) at
>   ControllerConnection.connectImpl (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:48:14)
>   at Function.ControllerConnection.connect (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\controllerConnection.js:31:27)
>   at HubLookup.getLocationService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\node_modules\microsoft-servicehub\hubLookup.js:19:80)
>   at HubClient.requestServiceWithRetries (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual ...

**Edit: Resolution**

I could not figure out how to resolve the issue, so I backed up my relevant information and factory reset my computer. I installed the appropriate versions of Microsoft Visual Studio and the software is working fine.

Comment: I've got eh exact same problem, and if you don't want to reset your OS, you're doomed, nothing seems to fix this for me.